# Can't edit list items inside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a problem by editing a list that keeps track of closed and open lockers in a school, the code I got to is the following:

```
y = list()
lockers = 100
students = 100
s = 2
i = 0
while i < lockers:
    y.append("O")
    i = i + 1
w = len(y)
while s <= students:
    for x in range(s, w, s):
        if y[x] == "O":
            y[x] = "C"
        if y[x] == "C":
            y[x] = "O"
    s = s + 1
openLockers = y.count("O")
print(openLockers)
```

The code is running smoothly without any errors but returns a value of 100. I have troubleshooted every variable and they all are being modified. I have concluded that the problems lies in the lines

```
y[x] = "C"
```

and

```
y[x] = "C"
```

The list is not changing at all after those lines.

I have added w in order to not use `len(y)` inside the range function and I cannot use

```
for i in y
```

because I need to a step between the items in the loop `y`.

I want to be able to modify the items in the list inside the loop or use a workaround...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a few other places where it can be simplified, but your real problem is here within the `for` loop:

```
if y[x] == "O":
    y[x] = "C"
if y[x] == "C":
    y[x] = "O"
```

If the locker is open, you set it to closed. Then, immediately, the next `if` statement executes, setting it back to open. Thus, you seemingly don't change `y`. Change the second `if` statement to an `elif` statement:

```
if y[x] == "O":
    y[x] = "C"
elif y[x] == "C":
    y[x] = "O"
```

This should fix your problem.

---

Now, this is separate and unnecessary but will simplify your code quite a bit. Try this (uses Boolean state instead of letters):

```
lockers = 100
students = 100
y = [False] * lockers

for s in range(2, students):
    for x in range(s, lockers, s):
        y[x] = not y[x]

openLockers = y.count(False)
print(openLockers)
```

Comment: Wow... I cannot believe i didn't catch that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichelChalfoun If you're interested, I edited and added some code that might be useful to you for learning purposes. :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know multiplying a list by an integers did that, and yes using booleans looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have just two possible values for `y[x]` which are `'O'` and `'X'`, you can use the following simplification in your code:

```
y[x] = "C" if y[x] == "O" else "O"
```